# JS issue when trying to convert strings to floats on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So lately I've been having a problem trying to convert strings from text inputs to floats/integers to use in an animation of sorts. any ideas? currently i'm trying to use the parsFloat, but that just stopped the circle from loading all together. is there any other ways to convert strings to floats? thanks!

```
function myFunction() { 

    var degrees = undefined;
    var Rad = function degToRad(x) {
        degrees = x/(180/Math.PI);
        return degrees;
    };

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var posX = 55, posY = 100, gravity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("drag").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("gravity").value), vX = parseFloat(document.getElementById("xVel").value), vY = 0;
    setInterval(function() {

        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(posX, posY, parseFloat(document.getElementById("radius").value), 0, Rad(360), false);
        c.fillStyle = "white";
        c.fill();

        posX+= vX;
        posY+= vY;

        if (posY > 800-parseFloat(document.getElementById("radius").value)) {
            vY *= -document.getElementById("bounce").value;
            posY = 800-parseFloat(document.getElementById("radius").value);
            vX *= 0.9;
        }

        vY += gravity;
    }, parseFloat(document.getElementById("framerate").value));

}
 </script>

</head>
<body>
  <input id = "gravity" type="text" placeholder="gravity (m/s)">
  <input id = "xVel" type = "text" placeholder="x velocity (m/s)">
  <input id = "bounce" type = "text" placeholder="bounce (0-1)">
  <input id = "radius" type = "text" placeholder="sphere radius">
  <input id = "Mass" type = "text" placeholder="sphere mass">
  <input id = "density" type = "text" placeholder="fluid density">
  <input id = "framerate" type = "text" placeholder="framerate (ms/frame)">
  <input id = "drag" type = "text" placeholder="drage co. (sphere = 0.5)">
  <input id = "submit" type = "submit" onclick="myFunction()">
  <button type="submit" onclick="location.reload()">done</button>
 <canvas id = "canvas" width="5000" height="800">

 </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: i suggest to parse a value only once and store the parsed value in a variable.

Comment: Looks like it is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/n1atr86d/

Answer (score 0):

You should filter and vet any input.

The following function is just an example. It vets the str, has constraints `min` and `max`. If it can't make a number it will default to a given value. It will find the first number in the string. It will not accept numbers using `e` (12e-10 or 9.245e34)

```
function vetNumber(str, defaultVal, min, max) {
    if(min === undefined || min === null){
        min = -Infinity;
    }
    if(max === undefined || max === null){
        max = Infinity;
    }
    if(defaultVal === undefined || defaultVal === null){
        defaultVal = 1;  // what the default defaultVal is is up to you.
    }
    if (typeof str === "string") {
        // extract a number
        // could have a leading - or . or -.

        str = /(-??([0-9]+\.?|\.?)[0-9]+)/.exec(str);
        if (str === null) {
            return defaultVal;
        }
        str = Number(str[0]); // convert to a number;
        return str < min ? min : str > max ? max : str;
    }
    if (typeof str === "number") {
        return str < min ? min : str > max ? max : str;
    }
    return defaultVal;
}
```

I like to use a number vet that also allows for constants and formulas, eg `PI` is `3.14...` and  `1/3` is `0.3333333` etc. I have found clients love such a feature as long as it is non intrusive.